# How is AC an angle bisector of $\angle PAB$?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Here is a problem involving tangent circles.

[image]
Let $\omega$ be a circle with a diameter $PQ$. Another circle $t$ is tangent to $\omega$ at $M$ and also tangent to $PQ$ at $C$. Let $AB$ be a segment such that $AB\perp PQ$. Also, $AB$ is tangent to $t$. Also $A\in\omega$ and $B\in PQ$. Prove that $AC$ bisects $\measuredangle PAB$.

Here is my approach:

Let $AB$ tangent to $t$ at $J$. According to the Archimedies' lemma, $M$, $J$, $Q$ are collinear. Also, $MQ\times QJ=QA^2=QN^2$.

Now consider an inversion $\Psi$ centered at $Q$ with radius $QA=QN$.
Note that $t$ gets maps to itself. So $\Psi(C)=C$.

Now it is clear that $QA=QN=QC$. So $C$ is the incenter of $\triangle PAN$. So, it implies that $AC$ is the angle bisector of $\measuredangle PAB$.

Comment: +1 to your question for nicely presented diagram, nice use of mathJax to display math, clear presentation of the problem, and documenting a reasonable effort to solve the problem.

Comment: Why do you think $AC$ is angle bisector of $\angle PAQ$? If $O$ is the center of circle $k$, $OA \perp AB$ and given $ABCO$ is a square, $AC$ is the angle bisector of $\angle OAB$ and cannot be angle bisector of $\angle PAQ$? I am going by your diagram.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.I had a mistake to write the problem.

Comment: How can you assume that $AB$ is tangent to $t$ at $J$? Seems to be that $A$ is any point on $\omega$. (Or did you miss out a condition?) $\quad$ Why is $MQ \times MJ = QA^2$? (Doesn't seem obvious to me, so can you add a line of reasoning?). $\quad$ Why does inversion map $t$ to $t$? $\quad$ How is $Q$ the incenter of $PAN$ when $Q$ doesn't lie in the triangle? Did you mean $C$? (esp to conclude that $AC$ is the bisector of $PAB$.)

Comment: Note that there is no need to type in mathjax mathematical relations "piece by piece". E.g. instead of `$UV$$=XY$` it is better to do the job in a breath, `$UV=XY$`. In case a macro is used, like in `$\angle PAB$`, just use a blank / a space after the macro. There is no need to artificially type `$\angle$$PAB$`. Also, in mathematical formulas it is always a good idea to insert spaces, so `$UV=XY$` is the same as `$UV = XY$` for the mathjax compiler, but the last version may be easier to edit and understand humanly. Please take a look at the edited question to see how things can be typed.

Comment: It seems to me that this is no longer a question but an answer..

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you see in figure $\angle PBC\neq\angle QBC$ but $\angle PDC=\angle CDQ=45^o$ which is easy to prove. angle CDQ is opposite to arc QE which equal to arc EP so angles opposite to this arcs are equal .

Comment: Can you clarify what is $D$? You seem to be answering a different question?

Comment: Extension of QB touches the circle at D. If you enlarge picture you can see that.

Comment: So $D=M$? or $D=A$?

Comment: @CalvinLin: This answer addresses the original version of the question (where $A$ was identified as the point of tangency of $\overline{AB}$ and the small circle), noting the flaw and offering a possible correction. OP has since made a different correction to the question (moving $A$ to the big circle), rendering this response obsolete.

Comment: @Blue Ah ic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give better details to some claimed properties in the figure, and provide arguments where the (implicit) posted question from my point of view did not come with a solid argument.

---

Here is my picture with some more ingredients for easy reference.

[image: math stackexchange inversion solution problem 4271781]

So let us recall. The points in the picture are constructed in a natural way in the following order. Start with $P,Q$. Let $O$ be the mid point of the segment $PQ$. Draw $(\omega)$, the circle centered in $O$ with radius $OP=OQ$. Pick some point $M\in(\omega)$ and draw the tangent in $M$ to $(\omega)$. It intersects $POQ$ in a point $S$. The angle bisector of $\measuredangle MSP$ intersects the radius $OM$ in a point $T$. We have $OTM\perp MS$. Let $C$ be the projection of $T$ on $POQS$. We draw the circle $(t)$ centered in $T$ with radius $TM=TC$. We draw the square $CTJB$ so that $B$ is between $C$ and $Q$. Let $A$ and $N$ be the two points of intersection of $JC$ with $(\omega)$.

We have to *show* that $AC$ bisects $\measuredangle PAB$.

---

Along the lines of the OP, we can argue as follows.

The two triangles $\Delta TMJ$ and $\Delta OMQ$ are isosceles in $T$, respectively $O$, and their angles in $T$, $O$ are equal since $TJ\| OQ$ (since both $TJ$, $OQ$ are perpendicular on $ABN$). So they are similar, so their angles in $M$ coincide, so $M$, $J$, $Q$ are colinear.

The power of the point $Q$ w.r.t. the circle $(t)$ is then
$$
QC^2=QJ\cdot QM\ ,
$$
and we consider the inversion $\Psi$ centered in $Q$ with this power, i.e. fixing $C$. For a handy notation of the inversion of a point $X\ne Q$, we alternatively denote the point $\Psi(X)$ by $X^*$.

Which is the image by this inversion of the (projective) line $AJBN$? It is a circle through the center of inversion $Q$. Since $QOP$ is perpendicular on this line, the center of this circle is on $QOP$. Since $J^*=M$ is on this circle, this circle is determined now, it is $(\omega)$.

In particular $B^*=P$ and $P^*=B$.

Where is the point $A^*$? From $A= QA\cap AJBN$ we get $A^*= (QA)^*\cap(AJBN)^*=QA\cap (\omega)=A$. So $A$ is also fixed by the inversion. This gives $QA=QC$. So the triangle $\Delta QAC$ is isosceles.
From here:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{CAB} 
&= \widehat{CAQ} - \widehat{BAQ}\\
&= \widehat{QCA} - \widehat{QPA}\\
&= \widehat{QAC} \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

---

*Observation:* From here we see that the incircle $(\kappa)$ of $\Delta PAN$ is centered in $C$, has the same size / radius as $(t)$, passes through $T$ and $B$.